# Vertical Text alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, vertical

I'm creating a tikzposter (using Xelatex) within which I want a number of text nodes arranged so the text is automatically positioned vertically, such as

> ```
> R
> i
> c
> h
> a
> r
> d
> ```

I have found a number of suggestions but they result in the text being rotated.

The closest method I've found to do this is to use a parbox and add spaces between each letter as such

```
\draw(270mm,158mm) node {\parbox{3pt}{R i c h a r d}};
```

However, as the intention is to automate drawing the nodes from an input file of names, I would prefer to avoid this. Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: [text width=3pt] is equivalent to \parbox{3pt}, but I take it you don't want to add the spaces between the letters.  You could create a macro to insert an \allowbreak after every letter automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing with the width.  You can use 0pt, but the resulting box also has zero width.  So I went with 1em and forced a linebreak after each letter.  I also centered the letters in the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\splitter}[1]{\splitterparse#1\END}
\def\splitterparse#1{\ifx\END#1
    \strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \else
    \null\hfil#1\newline
    \expandafter\splitterparse
  \fi}
\def\END{\END}% do not expand!  (Any unique string will do.)

\begin{document}
\tikz{\node[draw, inner sep=0pt]{\parbox{1em}{\splitter{Richard}}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you can define your own macro which would add spaces between letters. For example, this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\vpar}[1]{\parbox{3pt}{\makevpar#1\relax}}
\newcommand{\makevpar}[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{\relax}{}{#1 \makevpar}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(270mm,158mm) node {\vpar{Richard}};
  \draw(280mm,158mm) node {\vpar{Steven}};
  \draw(290mm,158mm) node {\vpar{Arnold}};
  \draw(300mm,158mm) node {\vpar{Micka{\"e}l}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Absorb one letter a time and make a tabular. The optional argument is for the vertical alignment with respect to the context.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verticaltext}[2][c]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
    \vertical@text{#1}#2\@nil
  \fi
}
\def\vertical@text#1#2#3\@nil{%
  \toks@={#2}%
  \@tfor\next:=#3\do{%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter\\\next}%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}\the\toks@\end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X \verticaltext{Richard} X \verticaltext[t]{Richard} X \verticaltext[b]{Richard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that accented characters should be braced:

```
\verticaltext{H{\'e}l{\`e}ne}
```

but this is not needed with XeLaTeX if you input `Hélène`.

A shorter implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\verticaltext}{O{c}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #2 }
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X \verticaltext{Richard} X \verticaltext[t]{Richard} X \verticaltext[b]{Richard}

\end{document}
```